# Getting an error while opening Information Link Spotfire 6.5.2

Tags: oracle11g, spotfire

We have recently upgraded from Spotfire 5.5 to 6.5.2.
I am getting the below error when clicked on 'Open Data' of any information link in Spotfire 6.5.2

---

Error message: Could not open information link.

TargetInvocationException at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (HRESULT: 80131604)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgressCancelable(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation, Boolean showCancelButton)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.ExecuteInformationLink(CachedInformationLinkElement informationLink)

ImportException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
Failed to open information link. (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.ConnectWithoutPrompting(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean updateInternalState)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.Connect(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean updateInternalState)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSource(InformationLinkDataSource dataSource, DocumentOpenSettings documentOpenSettings, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.InformationDesigner.DesignerFormController.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.DoOperationLoop()

InformationModelException at Spotfire.Dxp.Data:
An Internal Error has occurred. Illegal configuration: empty password (HRESULT: 80131500)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.GetJobSpecForId(Guid informationLinkId)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSource.GetJobSpec(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.InformationLinkDataSource.ConnectCore(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.ConnectWithoutPrompting(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean updateInternalState)

InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services:
An Internal Error has occurred. Illegal configuration: empty password (HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.WebServiceBase`1.InvokeService[T](ServiceMethod`1 serviceMethod, ExceptionFactoryMethod exceptionFactoryMethod)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Services.Data.InformationModel.QueryManagerService.GetJobSpecForId(Guid informationLinkId)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.InformationModel.InternalInformationModelManager.GetJobSpecForId(Guid informationLinkId)

---

Can anyone pls help?

Thanks !

Regards,
Shantanu

Answer (score 1):

the error is listed in the message:

InformationModelServiceException at Spotfire.Dxp.Services: **An Internal Error has occurred. Illegal configuration: empty password** (HRESULT: 80131509)

double check the Data Source that the Information Link is pulling from. add the credentials again and retest.